# Ruby on rails - API client - Faraday and Sawyer gem purpose

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I am building a Ruby on rails API client app.

People advise to use Faraday and Sawyer gem.
What is the use of Faraday , if I am not going to do anything with middleware.
What is Sawyer gem ? No documentation in github too.

Can anyone enlighten me ?

Answer (score 1):

For Faraday, here's a good article explaining why it's in need:
https://mislav.net/2011/07/faraday-advanced-http/

As to Sawyer, I'm also looking for something helpful but failed. Maybe there's really nothing about it now!